# About database design

Tags: mysql, database-design, nosql

I am considering data modeling (table design) And DB types(MySQL, MongoDB and so on).

I am thinking of a service that handles financial information and economic indicators.
Options have daily data by price range and by Special Quotation.On the other hand, economic indicators have daily or monthly data, and there is breakdown data. For example, the relationship between GDP and personal consumption, housing investment, etc.

In such a case, I would like to design a table that stores data as simply as possible, but what kind of architecture should I adopt?

Answer (score 1):

Having previously worked in Financial Tech, we primarily used Microsoft SQL Server to house all of our data.

If you plan to store data that relates to other data points, and / or need to ask questions about your data such as "what was the X trend for Y security over Z timeframe?" or "how often did a specific security trade over a certain timeframe?" then any RDBMS (Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc) will work for you.

If you're just looking for a place to dump highly varying unrelated data points that you're going to recall exactly as they are back into your application without the need for any less than very basic querying or data manipulation then a NoSQL database like MongoDB can work for you.

Comment: The biggest thing about picking a system to use is going to be the more technical needs than design needs. Concurrent access, hosting on servers, things like that. Not to mention having the knowledge of using it.

Comment: @JohnHerbert Well no, the design needs are a main definitive factor between choosing a **RDBMS** and a **NoSQL** system (based on structure or lack thereof), and both classes of systems support concurrent access and hosting on servers. But yes there are technical needs (which usually factor into design choices too) that differ such as distributed server horizontal scalability and tradeoffs between the **Consistency** guaranteed from the **ACID principals** of a **RDBMS** vs the **Availability** and **Partition** tolerance one might want from the **CAP theorem** supported in a **NoSQL** system.